# Give input from powershell script to python program?

Tags: python, powershell, input

Assume I have a python program that asks user their name and age.

```
name = raw_input("Name? ")
age = raw_input("Age? ")
print "I am " + name + " and I am " + age + " years old"
```

I have a powershell (Or bat) script that runs this Python program.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe prompt.py
```

How can I get the powershell script to auto-input letters/numbers to the python input to get the result (In which I can then export, or compare in Powershell)?

Comment: Why not skip Python and use `read-host` in PowerShell?

Comment: Students writing Python programs, want to have them auto-graded, so I don't have to do it manually.  Alt. is to just create a Java program.

Comment: Couldn't you stick to a Python based test suite that the students have to pass, as long as they pass the test suite they get most of their points after that a rubric concerning style, efficiency, commenting etc. (automated using something like pylint) could do the rest.

Comment: iLoveTux, do you have any simple test suites you recommend?  I only have experience using Python in a college course where we used PyGame.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I would read the python script in as a text file and check that the script contains certain logic and parameters until you where happy the script contained the correct methods.

In powershell its `$script = Get-Content C:\path\to\script.py` To load the script in as text, then check the it with regex or where and if statements.

**Original:**
This is just a limitation of how python expects input. You cannot do it without simulating key presses using something like autohotkey. Powershell will not support doing this without .net libraries and junk.

Ask if the effort required to implement a auto marking solution is worth it. If it is I would change the lesson so the students also setup arguments that can be parsed to the python script and if a argument is missing at runtime then prompt for input. then you can just use:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe prompt.py Name Age
```

Comment: This will happen for larger assignments